# how to make a loop that takes the different values if the string

Tags: python-3.x

I forgot my gmail password so i want to create a list that contains all my passwords for everything..hoping that one of them will be correct so i made the code below

```
import smtplib
server=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
server.starttls()
passwordList=["cows","dogs",monkeys","water"]
try:
for password in passwordList:
    server.login("MyEmail@gmail.com",password)
except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
     server.login("MyEmail@gmail.com",password)
#i need a code that will now uses the second string in the list password..what do you recommend i do
#since after the execution of the top part password will be put as cows and if it is not the correct one..the error smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError will be given and the program will stop so i added.try and except
    server.sendmail("MyEmail@gmail.com",Someone@gmail.com","password found")
```

Comment: You can't use the online forgot your password form?

Comment: cant remember  what I enter

Comment: i created it in 2010

Comment: ok.if you were to make one...what would you make

Comment: What's the difference between brute force programming it and trying those passwords online?

Comment: there  is no difference..its just that the list of password is like 200. I have them all saved in a file that I plan to access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting it out there, if you're going to write the list of passwords out anyways, why not just try every one of them...

ANYWAYS:

you have it pretty much right, just move your `try` to inside the for loop:

```
found = False
for password in passwordList:
    try:
        server.login("MyEmail@gmail.com",password)
        #anything past this line will ONLY be executed if the above line doesnt run an error (ie, the password was correct)
        found = True #change the boolean to True since the above line ran properly
        break #we already found the password so we can break out of the for loop
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        pass #since its the wrong password, just go on to the next password

if found: #will only execute if found was changed to true
    server.sendmail("MyEmail@gmail.com",Someone@gmail.com","password found")
```

the `found` bool is in case you go through the list and nothing was valid.

Comment: Thanks this works..could you please explain why you used the break,pass and the found